# How to get old value data select option when edit modal pop up using jquery in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

i try to show old value data when pop up modal show, but i still confuse about logic when select option data showing in modal, here is my code.

**Call the modal and function javascript**

```
<button
        class="btn text-white d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-capitalize btn-update me-2"
        data-bs-title="Edit" data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-id="{{ $item->id }}" data-bs-target="#edit_modal_users"
        style="background-color: #ff720c;width:50px;height:25px;font-size:12px; font-weight:500;"
        onclick="getDataMember('{{ $item->id }}','{{ $item->group_name }}', '{{ $item->role_name }}', '{{ $item->email }}')">
    Edit
</button>
```

**function javascript**

function getDataMember(id, group_name, role_name, email) {

```
        document.getElementById('user_id').value = id;
     
        document.getElementById('edit_department_name').value = group_name;
        document.getElementById('edit_role_name').value = role_name;
        document.getElementById('edit_email').value = email;

    }
```

**modal when pop up**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_modal_users" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalMessageTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="background: #19194b">
        <h6 class="font-weight-bolder text-white" style="font-weight: 600">Edit Member</h6>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close  text-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="card-text mt-4" id="basic-info">
          <div class="card-body pt-0">
            <form onsubmit="updateEmploye(event)">
              <div class="row">
                <input type="hidden" name="test" id="user_id">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <label class="form-label mt-2" style="color: black; font-weight:500">Department</label>
                  <div class="">
                    <select class="form-select " name="edit_department_name" id="edit_department_name">
                      <option value="">Select</option> @foreach ($data['list_department'] as $item_departement) <option value="{{ $item_departement->id }}" selected>
                        {{ $item_departement->group_name }}
                      </option> @endforeach
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <label class="form-label mt-2" style="color: black; font-weight:500">Role</label>
                  <div class="">
                    <select class="form-select " name="edit_role_name" id="edit_role_name">
                      <option value="">Select</option> @foreach ($data['list_role'] as $item_role) <option value="{{ $item_role->id }}" selected>{{ $item_role->role_name }}
                      </option> @endforeach
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <label class="form-label mt-2" style="color: black; font-weight:500">Role</label>
                  <div class="">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_email" name="edit_email">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row mt-2 ">
                <div class="d-flex mt-4 justify-content-end mb-0">
                  <div class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn text-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" style="background-color: #D42A34">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="sumbit" class="btn text-white" style="background-color: #62ca50">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

how to get old value use jquery?

Comment: So.. what you are asking for is to display the option item to be 'selected', when you open the modal box?

Comment: yes, i'm using pop up modal from bootstrap

Comment: Use the same section of code for both the select boxes you have..just change the selector of course!

Answer (score 0):

Try **replacing the code for select boxes** with these. You can go with any of these options:

**Jquery**

```
$('#edit_department_name').find('option').each((i, v) => { 
// check for each option text to be similar to our group name and 
// then add a selected attribute dynamically.
    if(group_name === v.text) {
        $(v).attr("selected", "selected");
    }
});
```

OR

```
$('#edit_department_name').find(`option[value="${group_id}"]`).attr("selected", "selected");
```

**Javascript:** As you have used

```
const departItems = (selector='#edit_department_name') => [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)]; // get all the option items
departItems(`#edit_department_name option`).map(o => (group_name === o.text) ? $(o).attr("selected", "selected") : '' ); // loop through all the items
```

Let people know which one worked for you.